# Show child div outside the width of parent jQuery dialog div

Tags: html, jquery, css, dialog

I am using jQuery dialog and I want an extra element(child div) defined inside the dialog which should look like it's attached to the dialog(parent div).

- I tried to use z-index and position(to child and parent div) but child div is not visible in the UI with dialog overlay.
- If I place the child div outside the parent div then it is visible but I don't want to add logic to place it next to the parent div because my parent div size is dynamic.

HTML

```
<div id="parent-div"></div>
<div id="child-div"></div>
```

Javascript/jQuery

```
$("#parent-div").dialog({
                    title: 'Parent',
                    width: parseInt(100, 100),
                    height: parseInt(190, 10),
                    modal: true,
                    buttons: [
                                {
                                    text: "Save",
                                    click: function () {
                                        $(this).dialog("close");
                                    }
                                }
                    ]
                });
var childdiv = document.getElementById("child-div");
document.getElementById("parent-div").appendChild(childdiv);
```

CSS

```
#child-div{
    height:20px;
    width: 20px;   
    left: -20px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3xp6wLse/2/)

[image: child div position in dialog]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `oveflow:visible` for both parents (`.ui-dialog` & `#parent-div`) to enable the visibility of the child element.

Your updated code would be like this

```js
$("#parent-div").dialog({
                    title: 'Parent',
                    width: parseInt(100, 100),
                    height: parseInt(190, 10),
                    modal: true,
                    buttons: [
                                {
                                    text: "Save",
                                    click: function () {
                                        $(this).dialog("close");
                                    }
                                }
                    ]
                });

var childdiv = document.getElementById("child-div");
document.getElementById("parent-div").appendChild(childdiv);
```

```css
#child-div{
    height:20px;
    width: 20px;   
    left: -20px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #000;
}

.ui-dialog, #parent-div {overflow: visible;}
```

```html
<div id="parent-div"></div>
<div id="child-div"></div>
```

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rkz85jge/1/)